# How edit footer copyright info?

Tags: posts, wp-query, customization, wp-editor, footer

I'm using XCODE wordpress theme .(https://www.codegearthemes.com/products/xcode).

Can anyone please suggest me how to edit copyright information in footer.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Potentially all wordpress theme have an documentation how to install and update theme content.

If you don't have the doc. I suggest 2 options here

1)There be theme setting in your wp admin panel, try to find out the footer options it have an text area where the copyright information will be added.

2)If first is not an option you have to find footer.php file in your theme and you will must be get it there.

Let me know if that helps.